# Is there a Spanish equivalent for the French word "voilà"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

A rough English translation for the French word "voilà" might be "there it is." One of my former Spanish teachers (an American, not a native speaker), would use the word "eso" in this context, in Spanish.

Is this a good translation? If not, what word would be? Or is there no good translation of "voilà" in Spanish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see a couple of words you can use: "¡ahí está!" or "¡eso!" (just like your teacher said).
I prefer the first one.

Comment: En un contexto informal, al menos en Madrid, a veces se puede oir "equilicuá" o "efestewie wonder" (creo que esta última equivale en inglés a "exactamondo"). Ambas son palabras de la [jerga de los 80](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movida_madrile%C3%B1a).

Comment: I just want to add that some people use it to say "Exacto" o "Exactamente" (Exactly) as a way to confirm something. As the same as ¡Ahí está!.

Comment: There is so much meaning of "voilà" in french... "voilà, voilà" at the end of a sentence with a special tone could mean "I told you so" or "I knew it"

Answer (score 7):

"He ahí" suena un poco anticuado, pero es adecuado:

> He ahí la casa que te dije -> Voilà la maison je l'ai dit

Mira la primera acepción de *he* en la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/he).

Comment: Todavía un poco más anticuado: Hete ahí (aunque siempre escuché o leí hete aquí, tengo entendido que también es válido)

Comment: Yo opino que *he ahí* es la mejor traducción de *Voilà*, a pesar de sonar en algunas circunstancias un tanto anticuado.

Comment: Me parece que en este caso no se usa Voilà. Sería Voici: "Voici la maison dont je t'ai parlé". Una coma o un signo de exclamación cambia toda la intención de la frase. Si quisieras usar Voilà sería así: "Voilà! C'est la maison dont je t'ai parlé"

Comment: Aunque es cierto que suena un poco anticuada, **¡He aquí!** me parece la forma que más se acerca a la expresión francesa _Voila!_

Comment: -> Voilà la maison je l'ai dit => mejor dicho: "Voilà ! La maison dont je t'ai parlé"

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use Voila. Everybody knows that word.

Comment: +1 Voila is universal!

Comment: It is not universal. I don't know it and I'm from Mexico.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo, no todo el mundo conoce Voilá y no es algo con lo que se te tome muy en serio

Answer (score 4):

In Spain, it is usually said:

> ¡Ya está! - Also can be used as "This is it" or "That's all".

or

> ¡Eso es!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, **voilà** has different nuances in French.

- When the meaning is "**I completely agree with what you are saying**", then I'd use "**Exacto**", or "**Exactamente**", or as others have said here, "**Eso**".
- When the meaning is "**There it is**", or "**Here is the thing**", then I'd use "**Aquí tienes**", or "**Toma**".

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase "!ahí está!" or "¡ándale!" is closer to voila.

Comment: "Ándale" as a way of expressing agreement sure works in Mexico, definitely.  (Not sure about other places.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is... there is no single word or expression with that exact meaning. Fortunately there is a lot of equivalent expressions, depending on the context.

Thus, "ahí está" and "he aquí" (formal/old, even equivalent to English *behold*) map reasonably well to "there it is" and hence to *voilà* --as otheres have noted-- in the sense of showing something you were expecting to *locate*. But depending on the meaning/surrounding situation you can also say "¡Mira!" (look!), "¡Eso!" ([that's] it), "¡Ya está!" or even "¡Listo!" (ready/done).

Answer (score 0):

Another equivalent would be "Ahí lo tienes"

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Sería interesante que añadieras algún tipo de referencia, ejemplo o explicación para que la respuesta sea más útil para todo el mundo. Puedes usar [edit] para hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Mi favorita

> helo ahí, helo aquí

Un galicismo sería directamente

> [vualá](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voil%C3%A0)

Answer (score -1):

Yo diría que puede traducirse como "Y listo" o "Ya está".

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. ¿Podrías intentar [edit]ar tu respuesta dando más detalles, referencias, ejemplos? Las respuestas con mayor detalle son más útiles para todo el mundo.